# How can I build a VBA script that takes an incoming email, modifies its body and forwards it?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I've managed to do the forward part.

```
Sub ScriptTest(item As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim NewMail As MailItem
    Dim obApp As Object
    Set obApp = Outlook.Application
    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)


     With NewMail
         .Subject = ""
         .To = "
         .Body = "REF " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "DOM" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf 

         .Importance = olImportanceHigh
         .Display
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    NewMail.Send
End Sub
```

I would like to take an incoming email and paste a specific string after the string I put in the script.

I did a rule then script setup in order to apply the script only with specific incoming mails.

Any help would be wonderful for me.

Comment: I just learned about NewMailEx event. Apparently, it could be a solution.

Comment: Work with `MailItem.Forward Method`

Comment: Don't need `obApp` within Outlook macro. Modifying the email body can be a lot of work for HTML emails. You need to insert in between the **body** tag.